# Matlab show image in gui

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I have been trying to show an image after browsing it. However, I have been getting errors like:

*??? Reference to non-existent field 'axes1'.
Error in ==> ImGui>Browse_Callback at 19
            axes(handles.axes1)
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback*

I have tried working with both predefined axes [like 'axes(handles.axes1);'] as well as with post-defined [like 'imshow(imgorg, 'Parent', handles.axes1);']. Unfortunately, both techniques have not worked out for me and I am consistently stuck with axes. I also tried making a customized axes and work with that but it also failed to show my image on the figure. Can anyone please identify/ rectify the problem in my code:

```matlab
function ImGui
    f =figure('Visible','on','Position',[460,200,700,385]);
    BrowseBt = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
                 'String','Browse','Position',[600,350,70,25],...
                 'Callback',@Browse_Callback);
    dispnames  = uicontrol('Style','text','String','',...
           'Position',[50,350,400,20]);
    movegui(f,'center');

    function Browse_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

        handles.output = hObject;
       [FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg;*.png','Select an image file',...
                                    'C:\Users\owner\Downloads\Conjunctiva\SGRH');

       fpname = strcat(PathName,FileName);
       dispnames  = uicontrol('Style','text','String',fpname,...
           'Position',[50,350,400,20]);
       imgorg = imread(fpname);

       handles.output = hObject;
       guidata(hObject, handles);
       axes(handles.axes1);
       imshow(imgorg);
%        ImAxes = axes('Parent', f, ...
%                  'Units', 'normalized', ...
%                  'position',[50 50 400 250]);
%              'HandleVisibility','callback', ...
%        imshow(imgorg, 'Parent', handles.axes1);
%        imshow(imgorg, 'Parent', handles.ImAxes);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [guidata](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) function.
*<sub>and reorganize your code a little bit</sub>*

You define all your uicontrols (button, textbox, axes etc ...) and you assign their handle to a structure (called `handles` here). Then when you GUI is fully defined, call `guidata` to store this handle structure in a place where any callback can access it.

Then in your callback function, call `guidata` again to retrieve this handle structure and get access to your objects (you axes and your textbox).

```
function ImGui
    f =figure('Visible','on','Position',[460,200,700,385]);
    handles.BrowseBt = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
                 'String','Browse','Position',[600,350,70,25],...
                 'Callback',@Browse_Callback);
    handles.dispnames  = uicontrol('Style','text','String','',...
           'Position',[50,350,400,20]);
    handles.ImAxes = axes('Parent', f, ...
             'Units', 'pixels', ...
             'position',[30 30 640 300],...
             'visible','off');
    movegui(f,'center');
    guidata(f,handles) ;

    function Browse_Callback(hObject, eventdata) 
       handles = guidata(hObject);

       [FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg;*.png','Select an image file');
       fpname = strcat(PathName,FileName);

       imgorg = imread(fpname);

       set(handles.dispnames,'String',FileName)
       set(handles.ImAxes,'visible','on') ;
       imshow(imgorg, 'Parent', handles.ImAxes);
       guidata(hObject, handles);
    end
end
```

In this specific case you don't really need to call `guidata` again at the end of the callback to store the values again but it is good practice, in case you modified something you want the changes to be saved.

Comment: Thanks Hoki. It worked. One minor improvement needed, what should i do to make the ImAxes visible only when the image is displayed on Gui?

Comment: @Hasan. I edited the answer. You just set the axes `visible` property to `off` when you create it, then you make it visible only when you need it.

Comment: It is awesome. That now leads to another problem: I have to pass the image read in the Browse_Callback function to another function. I am trying to do it like, I create another push button and upon its click, I have to pass the image into the next function:
       handles.AnalyzeBt = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
                 'String','Analyze',...
                 'Callback',@Analyze_Callback);
       guidata(hObject, handles);
             
        function Analyze_Callback(hObject, eventdata, imgorg)
           handles = guidata(hObject);
           rim = imgorg(:,:,1);

Comment: @Hasan, use [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) to save your image data after you read it. Then use `getappdata` to retrieve it when you need it in your other function.

Comment: I tried working with setappdata & getappdata but got the following error:
_Conversion to double from struct is not possible.
Error in ==> ImGui>Browse_Callback at 36
       setappdata(handles, 'ImageFile', imgorg);_
Here is how i am doing this:
`guidata(hObject, handles);
       setappdata(handles, 'ImageFile', imgorg);
                    
       function Analyze_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
           
           handles = guidata(hObject);
           img1 = getappdata(handles, 'ImageFile');
           rim = img1(:,:,1);`

Comment: the first argument of `setappdata` needs to be the handle of an actual component (not just the structure containing the collection of handles). So use `setappdata(handles.ImAxes, 'ImageFile', imgorg);` and `img1 = getappdata(handles.ImAxes, 'ImageFile');`